# How to pass a DataTable to a model and display in MVC using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, datatable

I am getting some data from the database(Oracle) in datatable. I need to bind this data to a table on View. My datatable has around 10 columns, and I want to display all of them on the table. I also have 3 other tables on the same page and all of them have around 8 columns and using 3 separate datatables for getting data from database. So all together 4 datatables and around 40 columns.

My questions are:

1. How to assign the values of the 40 columns to my properties in the model?
2. I heard I should not user datatable to pass data to view. Is this correct? If yes why?

If what am currently doing is not a good way of programming please let me know how to do this.

For example, I have a model with the follwing properties:

```
public class Properties
public property firstname as string
public property lastname as string
public propery gender as string
public property phonenumber as string
public property homenumber as string
public property city as string
public property state as string
public property country as string
etc...
End Class
```

in my controller:

```
Dim prop as new Properties
Dim dao as DataObject
Dim dt, dt1, dt2, dt3 as new datatable

dt = dao.getDetails(userID)
dt1 = dao.getInformation(firstName)
dt2 = dao.getContactDetails(phonenumber)

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
  prop.firstname = Convert.ToString(dt.rows.Item("FirstName"))
    etc...
End If
If dt1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
  prop.state = Convert.ToString(dt.rows.Item("State"))
    etc...
End If
If dt2.Rows.Count > 0 Then
  prop.Country = Convert.ToString(dt.rows.Item("Country"))
    etc...
End If
```

Comment: Would it be ok to pass the data to your view using an ajax call and return your model as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method which assigns the values from the various datatables to your model (if you only want one model)  (this can be done in your controller, or another service)

Then, you pass your model into the view.

Within your view, you simple reference the model properties to assign them where you need them

Alternatively,  you can create a model to map each datatable, then user a viewmodel to attach each model and pass the viewmodel to your view.

Comment: Can you plz give me some sample code for writing a method which assigns the values from data tables to models and also using the view model approach as well